How to choose the suitable shortcut/combination in SAPUI5?
I have a function onRun. I want to create a shortcut combination to execute this function. How can I choose the suitable combination? I have tried so many combinations but none is working.
manifest.json
"sap.ui5": {
  "commands": {
    "Run": {
      "shortcut": "Ctrl+Shift+Q"

*.view.xml
<Page showHeader="false">
  <Panel />
  <dependents>
    <core:CommandExecution command="Run" execute=".onRun" />
  </dependents>
</Page>



How can I choose the suitable combination?

You can see the valid and the list of disallowed shortcuts currently only in the source code: sap/ui/core/util/ShortcutHelper.js.
I've requested a public enhanced documentation regarding the shortcut at OpenUI5 Docs Issue #20. Give it a .


I have tried so many combinations but none is working.

I see no issues in your snippets so far, except that the Page might be missing a focusable element. When testing the shortcuts, note that focus-independent or focus-less command execution is not allowed as of this writing. Cf. OpenUI5 Issue #2788.
